# Handle finite integral of unbounded function

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to show that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that in the measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu),\, u \in \mathcal{L}^1$:

$\forall E \in \mathcal{A}: \mu(E) < \delta \Rightarrow  |\int_E u\,d\mu|<  \frac{1}{100}$

I can show this if u is bounded. However, the problem is if u is unbounded. Then the integral can still be finite, e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$.

I can't find a delta when u is unbounded.

Any hint/help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering $u^{+}$ and $u^{-}$ we can reduce the proof to the case when $u \geq 0$.

Suppose there is no such $\delta$. Then for each $n$ there exists $E_n$ such that $\mu (E_n)<\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ and $\int_{E_n} u d\mu>\frac 1 {100}$.   Let $E=\lim\sup E_n$. Then $\mu(E)=0$, so  $\int_E u d\mu=0$. But $\int_E u d\mu = \lim \int_{\cup_{j\geq n} E_j} u  d\mu \geq \lim\int_{ E_n} u d \mu \geq \frac 1 {100}$ which is  contradiction.

Proof of the fact that $\mu (E)=0$: $\mu (E)=\mu (\cap_n \cup_{j \geq n} E_j) =\lim_n \mu (\cup_{j \geq n} E_j)\leq \lim_n\sum_{j \geq n} \frac 1 {2^{n}} =0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u\in L^1$, $u$ is finite almost everywhere.

Therefore $|u|\land N:=min\{|u|, N\}$ monotonically increases and converges to $|u|$ a.e. as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Choose sufficiently large $N$ so that $\int_{X}|u|d\mu-\int_{X}(|u|\land N)d\mu=\int_{X}(|u|-|u|\land N)d\mu<\epsilon$. Note that the integrand is always positive.

Since $\int_{E}(|u|\land N)d\mu\leq N\mu(E)$, you can now choose $E$ with sufficiently small $\mu(E)$ so that $\int_{E}(|u|\land N)d\mu<\epsilon$.

Combining the previous lines proves what you need. Just set $\epsilon=\frac{1}{200}$.

Comment: Very nice, but how do you calculate the $\epsilon=\frac{1}{200}$ ?

Comment: Are you asking how I knew $\epsilon=\frac {1}{200}$ would do? Because my proof shows that if you choose sufficiently small $\delta $, $\int_{E} |u|d\mu <2\epsilon $. To make $2\epsilon=\frac {1}{100} $, which is what you demand, that is an obvious choice. $